# SearchView in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm using the SearchView widget in ActionbarSherlock as a follows:

**File.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.MenuSearch).getActionView();
   searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
   searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
   searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

   return true;
}
```

**File.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/MenuSearch" android:title="@string/Bs"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:showAsAction="always|withText"
       android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" >
    </item>

</menu>
```

In my application I get to show the search icon and select it unfolds the search box for the widget, but when I write any search I do not know how to interact with the widget SearchView to launch a new activity and show a series of results.

With the command `searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);` appears a icon similar to 'play' and I suppose it is for just that, but I do not know how to interact with it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Official android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) describes how start new activity to handle search query and display results.

First you need to create (if you havent already) searchable configuration in `res/xml/searchable.xml`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Set this configuration for your activity, that contains SearchView in actionbar, like this (in manifest):

```
<activity ... >
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

</activity>
```

So basically, you need your searchable activity (new activity that will start after submitting search query) to handle the `android.intent.action.SEARCH` action. Declare it in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" ... >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</activity>
```

And your searchable activity should look like this:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }
    ...
}
```